# flask: code in app factory does not get executed

Tags: flask

I am using the standard flask app factoty setup as stated here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/

flaskr/**init**.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    print('Hello World')

   ...

    return app
```

I run this app with:

> export FLASK_APP=flaskr
>
> export FLASK_ENV=development
>
> flask run

All very standard. But why is the code print("hello world") never executed?

## edit

After reboot of my dev sytem the issue is gone. I am sorry I posted this.

Comment: do you see `* Serving Flask app "flaskr" .... * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)...`  when you run the application ?

Comment: yes. Flask is started normally. But the print statement is missing in execution. That is the strange part.

Comment: If I start app explicity e.g. with a startup file: ```app.run()``` then I see the print statement.

Comment: oh,oh, after reboot of my dev system, the issue is gone. the print statement gets executed even with startup type ```flask run```

Comment: glad it works now, you can delete the post if the error is not really reproducible

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you named the file `init.py` instead of `__init__.py`.

Comment: i think it's only a markup trap, `__` is used to bold font

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an older version of flask (<1.0).
The newest versions (>1.0) allow to detect automatically the function `create_app` or `make_app` ([source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0bb25eb3673904179e772f4b7376ecc7fbe4822f/flask/cli.py#L71)) to launch the application from CLI `flask` command.

You can update the flask package, for example with **pip** :

```
pip install --upgrade Flask
```

or add the following lines at the end of the `__init__` file to create the application in an explicit way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

Comment: "version": "==1.0.2"